# Why convert IP to integer for the purpose of storing it?

Tags: database, networking, ip

everyone talks about how to convert IP addresses to an integer for storing, but what are the actual reasons for this approach to be propagated?
What benefits/disadvantages does it have?

In short: **why** should I do it?

Comment: To be able to sort correctly and do math on the IP addresses. In the packet headers, IPv4 addresses are 32-bit integers, and IPv6 addresses are 128-bit integers. The network devices use them that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are few generic reasons, like integers take less space than strings, but just wanted to emphasis the main one: IP addresses are in fact numbers.

We humans prefer IP addresses string representations, like "10.0.0.1" or "2002::2" to make our life easier. In fact, most operation on IPs are strictly numeric. For example, masking (IP & mask), checking IP range (first < IP < last) etc.

So, just like string representation of a number we convert to an integer type ("123" -> 123), string representation of IP should be converted to its integer form ("10.0.0.1" -> 0x0A000001 or 167772161).

Comment: I agree with you. IP addresses are whole numbers (the definition of integer, although they often do not meet the integer definition of some programming languages). There is one who strongly disagrees (see the comments @ https://stackoverflow.com/q/45067655/3745413).

Comment: In today's world, a plus of like 5 extra bytes doesn't really matter anymore, right? But I understand you pointed it out as a matter of principle.

Comment: @Kapparina depends how many IPs you have ;) If it is a database of connections (flows), those 5 extra bytes times millions (billions) of records times few IPs per each record... Then the queries. String representation of the same IP may differ, say "10.0.0.1" is basically the same as "010.000.000.001". So to select all 10.0.*.* connections you have to take into account those possible different representations. Summing up. There are no advantages to store IPs as strings, but there might be technical limitations.

Comment: I get your point. Though, I only need to save single IPs or a range for several thousand entries.